# as his father played pool

Tags: meaning, adverbials

a. As his father played pool, so did he.

I think (a) can mean that he played pool because his father did, or that they played pool at the same time.

Could it mean that he played pool in the same manner as his father?

Comment: All 3 interpretations are possible. Also (more likely if it starts ***Just as** his father played...*) it might simply mean that *the fact of him playing pool **reflects the fact that his father did this*** - with no particular implication that the *way* they played was similar. Only context will tell you which meaning applies (there may be others we haven't thought of).

Answer (score 1):

No, typically the phrase "*as [someone] did*" or "*like [someone]*" is used to indicate similarity or comparison in terms of behavior or action.
In this case, "*As his father played pool, so did he*" simply means that he also played pool like his father, either at the same time or because his father introduced him to the game. It doesn`t imply anything about playing pool in a similar manner as his father.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence "*As his father played pool, so did he*" implies that he played pool because his father did. It suggests a relationship where his father's action of playing pool influenced him to also play pool.

While the sentence doesn't explicitly convey the idea of playing pool in the same manner as his father, it does leave room for interpretation. Depending on the context and additional information, it could be inferred that he played pool in a similar manner as his father. However, to emphasize again, without further clarification, the sentence itself does not indicate that they played pool in the same manner.